# Zip function in typed racket with rest arguments

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, typed-racket

I'm struggling with the syntax for a function that zips together any number of lists. I currently have:

`(define (zip . [lsts : (Listof Any) *])
  (apply map (inst list Any) lsts))`

Which causes the following error when evaluated:

> Error: struct:exn:fail:syntax /Applications/Racket
>   v6.6/collects/racket/private/kw.rkt:929:25: Type Checker: Bad
>   arguments to function in `apply':
>
> Domains: (-> a b ... b c) (Listof a)
>   (Listof b) ... b
>
> (-> a c) (Pairof a (Listof a))
>
> Arguments: (-> Any * (Listof Any)) (Listof (Listof Any)) *
>
> in: (#%app apply map (#%expression list) lsts)

Since these evaluate okay:

`(apply map (inst list Any) '(("asd" 1 2) ("cat" 3 4)))
;;(("asd" "cat") (1 3) (2 4))`

`(define (test . [lsts : (Listof Any) *])
  lsts)
(test '(1 2 3) '(2 3 "dogs"))
;;((1 2 3) (2 3 "dogs"))`

I think the type checker's complaining about `apply` failing whenever no arguments are passed in, since I get a similar error trying to evaluate the following:

```
(apply map (inst list Any) '())
```

> Error: struct:exn:fail:syntax /Applications/Racket
>   v6.6/collects/racket/private/kw.rkt:929:25: Type Checker: Bad
>   arguments to function in `apply':
>
> Domains: (-> a b ... b c) (Listof a)
>   (Listof b) ... b
>
> (-> a c) (Pairof a (Listof a))
>
> Arguments: (-> Any * (Listof Any)) Null *
>
> in: (#%app apply map (#%expression list) (quote ()))

But I'm not sure how to specify to the function that it'll take at least one argument (list).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `map` needs to take at least one list as an argument. Consider what would happen if you called `zip` with zero arguments. Then you would be calling `map` with zero lists, which isn't allowed. So, you have to restrict your `zip` function to take one or more arguments. You can do that by specifying an argument before the rest argument like this:

```
#lang typed/racket

(define (zip [lst : (Listof Any)] . [lsts : (Listof Any) *])
  (apply map (inst list Any) lst lsts))
```

One more thing: This would be better if it were polymorphic.

```
#lang typed/racket

(: zip : (∀ (A) (-> (Listof A) (Listof A) * (Listof (Listof A)))))
(define (zip lst . lsts)
  (apply map (inst list A) lst lsts))
```

Notice that the domain still needs to be `(Listof A) (Listof A) *` and not just `(Listof A) *`.

**Update: Even more polymorphism**

It's actually possible to make the polymorphism on this even better, so that if you give it exactly 3 lists, it produces a list of exactly-3-element lists. This version of `zip` would have the type

```
(: zip : (∀ (A B ...)
            (-> (Listof A)         ; first input
                (Listof B) ... B   ; next n inputs, where n is the number of B type-arguments
                (Listof (List A B ... B)))))
```

However, if the body were `(apply map list lst lsts)`, the `list` function would need the type

```
(∀ (A B ...) (-> A B ... B (List A B ... B)))
```

However, `list` used as a function value only has the type `(All (a) (-> a * (Listof a)))`. Instead we can define a new function `listd`, which behaves exactly like `list`, but with the new type

```
;; (listd x y z) = (list x y z)
;; but it's assigned a type that's more convenient for `zip`
(: listd : (∀ (A B ...) (-> A B ... B (List A B ... B))))
(define (listd a . bs)
  (cons a bs))
```

Using this, the dots-polymorphic version of `zip` can be defined like this:

```
(: zip : (∀ (A B ...)
            (-> (Listof A)         ; first input
                (Listof B) ... B   ; next n inputs, where n is the number of B type-arguments
                (Listof (List A B ... B)))))
(define (zip lst . lsts)
  (apply map (inst listd A B ... B) lst lsts))
```

Using it:

```
> (zip (list 'a 'b 'c) (list 1 2 3) (list "do" "re" "mi"))
- : (Listof (List (U 'a 'b 'c) Positive-Byte String))
'((a 1 "do") (b 2 "re") (c 3 "mi"))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the comprehensive answer! I had been trying something along the similar lines to your answer but for some reason had decided that `cons`ing `lst` with `lsts` was a good idea, then gave up when it didn't work and resorted to a `zip` that only took 2 arguments. I'll use this from now on though. Good shout on the polymorphic signature as well.

Answer (score 0):

> I think the type checker's complaining about apply failing whenever no arguments are passed in

Correct. If you just want to assert that there will be at least one argument, without doing anything fancy with arity polymorphism:

```
(define example (cast '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6)) (Listof (Listof Number))))
(apply map (inst list Number) (assert example pair?))
```

The key piece of code here is `(assert example pair?)`, which asserts that `example` is not an empty list. Typed Racket did not cause this problem - it is trying to protect you from the possibility of `example` being empty (with an unhelpful error message). `assert` bypasses Typed Racket's check without fixing this problem. However, `(inst list Number)` is required due to [limitations in Typed Racket.](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/caveats.html#%28part._.Type_inference_for_polymorphic_functions%29)