# Instantiate the type of the "rest" parameter of a variadic polymorphic procedure when arity is not known in advance in typed Racket

Tags: polymorphism, racket, variadic-functions, typed-racket

Let's say I want to transpose a 2 x n "matrix" (list of lists) `mat`. The idiomatic way of doing so in racket is

```
(apply map list mat)
```

To do the same thing in typed/racket, I have to help the type checker a little. The type of `map` in that case is

```
(All (c a b ...) 
  (-> (-> a b ... b c) (Listof a) (Listof b) ... b (Listof c)))
```

Since I'm dealing with a 2 x n matrix, I must instantiate both a and b as `Number`:

```
(apply (inst map (Listof Number) Number Number) 
       (inst list Number)
       mat)
```

If `mat` was a 3 x n matrix,

```
(apply (inst map (Listof Number) Number Number Number)
       (inst list Number)
       mat)
```

Would do the trick. Now, let's say that I'm dealing with an m x n matrix where m is some unknown positive integer. Is there a general way of instantiating map that would work for any value of m?

Comment: I think this is exactly what you want https://stackoverflow.com/a/44864244/718349

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Sorawee Porncharoenwase, that pretty much solved my problem. Here's what I've done:

1. Define a polymorphic `zip` function as in the link provided:

```
(: zip (∀ (a) (-> (Listof a) (Listof a) * (Listof (Listof a)))))
(define (zip lst . lsts)
  (apply map (inst list a) lst lsts))
```

2. Apply it to `mat`:

```
(apply zip (car mat) (cdr mat))
```